Convergence of series of rational function after splitting using long division
Let $A_k$ and $B_k$ be sequences of polynomials $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that $\deg A_k \geq \deg B_k$ and $\deg A_k - \deg B_k$ is bounded. Performing polynomial division:
$$ \frac{A_k(z)}{B_k(z)} = P_k(z) + \frac{Q_k(z)}{B_k(z)} $$
where $P_k$ is polynomial of degree $\deg A_k - \deg B_k$ and $Q_k$ is polynomial of degree $\deg(Q_k) < \deg B_k$.
I want to prove that, if the series
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A_k(z)}{B_k(z)} $$
converges absolutely away from the poles of $B_k$, then so do the series $\sum_k P_k(z)$ and $\sum_k \frac{Q_k(z)}{B_k(z)}$.
Furthermore, under what circumstances is $\lim_{z \to \infty} \sum_k \frac{Q_k(z)}{B_k(z)}= 0$?
